# If/else and file_exists function in htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, lamp

I don't really know how to explain this situation but i give it a try. So, I have this url: 
**http://localhost/static/some_picture.png**, and my folders look something like this:

- statics/x/picture.png
- statics/y/logo.png

What I want is that if the user types the mentioned url, he will see the "picture.png" what is in the "statics/x/picture.png", but if he types **http://localhost/static/some_logo.png** then he will see the "logo.png" in the "statics/y/logo.png".

My last try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond statics/x/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/x/$1  [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond statics/y/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/y/$1  [L]
```

Currently i have this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/x/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/x/$1  [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/y/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/y/$1  [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but your `-f` condition isn't right.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/x/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /statics/x/%1  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/y/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /statics/y/%1  [L]
```

Comment: I see how you are thinking, and i understand you code, but somehow it's just not working, i really dont know why, my whole code is like: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/x/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /statics/x/%1  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/y/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /statics/y/%1  [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule> `

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/x/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/x/$1  [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^static/some_(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/statics/y/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^static/some_(.*)$ statics/y/$1  [L]
```

the trick is to use [RewriteCond backreference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) , which syntax is like `%1` , to match grouped parts on the previous RewriteCond.

Also, thanks **Jon Lin** for noticing that the RewriteCond `-f` option needs an absolute local path.

**Update**: Added %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} to RewriteCond -f , found out by **Jon Lin**

Comment: Still nothing, no errors as far as i can see but on the other hand its not working too.